# Tensorflow: index per row

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a Tensor of shape (100,20). Now I also have a Tensor of indices of shape (100,). How to obtain now a Tensor of shape (100,) or (100,1) with per row (100 rows) the right value (selected by the corresponding index in indices?

Small example:
So let's say tensor A is

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

and tensor B is

```
[0,2,1]
```

then I want as output

```
[1,6,8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join your B tensor with an appropriate range to create two-dimensional indices (in your example `[[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 1]]`) and then extract the elements using `tf.gather_nd`:

```
b_2 = tf.expand_dims(b, 1)
range = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(b)[0]), 1)
ind = tf.concat(1, [range, b_2])
res = tf.gather_nd(a, ind)
```

Comment: Thanks this works, hope Tensorflow will have nicer code for this in future releases

Comment: While working for the simple example, this does not work when the 100 is an unknown dimension. Then the error is: ValueError: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor. Do you also have a solution for this?